# Model view Controller implementation QT

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

i'am a beginner in c++/QT and so i shuld make a Programm that put values from 2 QEditText fields in a table with a pushbutton.
When the name from the value exist, came a QMessageBox. 
When i klicked on a Header from the table, they sorted it A-Z .
But now my boss will that i make  ist in a MVC- konzept.
I have reading a lot of things about that, but i don't now, how i implemented it  in my projekt.
can anybody help me or give a tip ? 
I'am speak germany and not so good english, so you can write in german :)

I have a Table.h where the class Tabelle : QWidget , and who i deklare my slots and my Editfields etc.

than i have a Tabelle.cpp that includes Tabele.h here i have all my method's like the pushbuttonklick slot, in this slot i sorting the Items and look if they alredy exist , too .

and a mothod " init " where i build the labels , edit fields , put the Objekts in a Layout and all so .

Than i have a TabelleMain.cpp where i " Started " my programm

```
QApplication myapp(argc,argv);
 Tabelle tabelle;
 tabelle.init();
```

return myapp.exec();

how i must cange my programm and what I  need to add ? 
Thank's for helping me :) !

Comment: Probably is it best for you to really understand the concepts behind MVC pattern before starting the project. Once you understand MVC you cand easily model your problem. A first hint can be this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: yes, i have read 10 tuturials or more, but i don't know how i have make that in my programm .  With a simple projekt where i have set and get a String from a textfield , i have understand it , but my program is the Problem , not the MVC per se.

Answer (score 0):

If I refer to the link Ispas Claudiu gave you, the first thing you have to pay attention is:

"(MVC model) It divides a given software application into three interconnected parts"

Qt uses a model/view approach so I think it's a waste of time to separate the controller from the view in your simple example.

The first thing you have to do is to create two directories Model, View.

In Model folder, you could have a class Container which manage values you want to display in your table.
In View folder, you could have some class which manage all the GUI part (QMessageBox, QTextEdit, etc...)

With signal/slot, it's very easy to connect these two parts.